# Wrong results between plugins ReSharper CLT and Resharper in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

The results of the check error in my code using `VisualStudio 2022 plugin Resharper version 2021.3.4` and `Resharper in CLT 2021.3.4` are completely different. Used the same file `.DotSettings`

There are no bugs in the `IDE VisualStudio 2022`, but using the CLT there are over 2000.

I checked the results in TeamCity and they match with CLT.

Who have encountered, tell me how to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue almost a year ago and contacted the JetBrains support. We had a very long back and forth, from which I took the following key aspects:

- There are some existing issues, for example [this one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-461819).
- Make sure that no other settings layer (e.g. machine-wide config) comes into your way and overrides certain settings.
- Enable *solution-wide analyses (SWA)*, as it comes closer to what R# CLT does.
- The whole picture becomes even more fuzzy when using Rider. For example, I had to enable **File | Settings | Editor | Inspection Settings | " Enable computationally expensive inspections"**
- There are different results shown, depending on the used tool window.

  - Rider

    - SWA
    - *Code → Inspect Code*
  - VS

    - SWA
    - *ReSharper → Inspect → Code Issues in Solution*

So my key take-away was: it is super-hard to reach a 100% sync of VS and R# CLT, which gets even more complex when Rider comes into play. The almost inexhaustible number of options to configure R# makes it impossible to answer your general question.
What I can recommend: try to reduce the problem to a very small solution and get in contact to JetBrains.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this was corrected in the new version of `R# 2022.1.0` at JetBrains (using the Blazor component, files were created with the extension `.razor`, which R# checks did not take into VS)

That solved my problem